# How to detect Minecraft Singleplayer LAN port

Tags: javascript, cpu-usage, web-worker

**Some Backstory**
So I really need help with this project I am making that is suppose to try to find an open port from my Minecraft SinglePlayer LAN. As making something like that is easier then creating a server. To help with my project, I use this API https://mcapi.us/, which helps getting the status.

Firstly, I did try to use a for loop to loop through a huge range but with registering it through the API, it overloads my computer CPU. Secondly, I tried finding some help online and found about web workers and saw I could divide up work. It was about perfect but then seen that I cannot use the API (The most important part) on it as the elements that is in the API, web-workers cannot use.

**The Problem:**
So the problem is that I cannot properly range through a huge number like 10000 to 65535 as just running that through the API method overloads my CPU. I have also tried using PHP as well but no luck as it takes too long to read through all the numbers. I am probably going to have to use PHP though as it seems to be more powerful. But I need some way to get the Minecraft Singleplayer LAN port and I can't find any way to do that at all.

**Reason:**
The reason I need some way to access it is so I can make a web application to post the port the Minecraft Singleplayer LAN is running on and if offline will say another message. This way I can just send the web url to a friend and they can continuously just copy and paste the address and port for easy access so I don't have to keep sharing the port as that is non-efficient. One more thing as well, I am using Minecraft version that is *before* 1.13, *not* at 1.13 or after.

Question Update:
I have in fact made this question more clear to what I originally meant as what I said people was unclear so I updated this to be more clear. Plus Stack Overflow is kinda forcing me to make it more clear. So here, I hope this is clear for everyone.

Comment: Why not just host the other script on your own domain?

Comment: Well, I do have one on my own domain as well, but when I use that one, it just says "window is not defined."

Comment: Doing a portscan should never be a part of regular operation, and definitely not be orchestrated from a web worker.

Comment: @Bergi What do you mean?

Comment: While you haven't shown your code, from the description it sounds like you're trying to make 55535 API requests from that web worker?

Comment: @Bergi Okay, well if you want, I can put in the code for you. Might be a bit messy as I've been trying to mess with it to try to make it work. I just really need this to work, I'll take about any help at this point.

Comment: Well if that's your plan, you don't need to post the code. You cannot make 50k HTTP requests from a webpage, not even from a web worker. You will need to find a better approach.

Comment: @Bergi I think you are confused now. Let me try to put it here a bit simpler. I need to for loop a port range from 10000 to 65535. But when I did it at first, it froze my computer a bit, so got an idea for web workers and to divide up work.to make it run smoother but when exporting the data out to be run by the api, it froze my computer up a bit. So I tried to putting it in the web workers but it was undefined. Do you have any suggestions though for a better approach if you did understand?

Comment: @JonathanJ.Pecany A loop of ~50k iterations is nothing, and can finish in milliseconds. What exactly are you trying to compute *inside* that loop?

Comment: @Bergi Well go to this link. https://mcapi.us/#usage, that method that is says, I am doing something similar to that. It loops and it will loops through there until it finds a port is being used. It is so I can open my minecraft single player Lan world and it will automatically find the port so I don't have to continuously share different ports.

Comment: So I'm not confused, you are really trying to call that api method 55535 times? Well, sorry, this is just not viable. (Regardless whether you use web workers or not).

Comment: @Bergi Really, I am quite sad to hear this news. Any other methods I could use to accomplish this. Any at all, doesn't matter if it is new code or not. I need some way for it to do this. Like maybe I could do it in chunks or something.

Comment: The proper solution to your problem is a [service discovery protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_discovery). If you really need to do a portscan to find the server, don't do it from a web browser but use a dedicated tool.

Comment: @Bergi Okay, thanks. I never really learned about service discovery protocol. Mind sharing some info about those? Mainly with the dedicated tool?

Comment: @Bergi So how would I use this for my problem? I am again new to that part.

Comment: The first step would be to research which protocols your target (ie. minecraft) supports.

Comment: Okay, what would I do next after doing some researching?